# How do I call the void on another page when I click on the button?

Tags: c#, .net, methods

I have a Module.cs, I want to run void which is inside of the module when I click the button. How can I call the void?

Module.cs:

```
public void CreateInventorApplication()
{
    // İnventorün Yüklenmesini Bekle
    while (!InvApp.Ready)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
    }

    DefaultCaption = InvApp.Caption;
    InvApp.Visible = true;
    WatchTimer.Enabled = true;

    StatusType = StatusTypeEnum.Online;
    StatusMessage = "InventorPreparing";

}
```

Form1.cs:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Do you want to call CreateInventorApplication method from your form button click handler ? Your question isn't clear. Also provide the code that's in Module.cs

Comment: Yes I want to call CreateInventorApplication method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have phrased this a little ambiguously, but I'll assume you want to run "CreateInventorApplication" when you click the button.

Your click event method needs a reference to an instance of your Module class. You will need to create an instance of Module, make that instance available to your button1_Click method, and then call it. You could do something like this.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create an instance of the Module class that the button click event can access.
    Module myModule = new Module();
    // Call the void function using the instance we just created.
    myModule.CreateInventorApplication();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your void needs to be public, otherwise it is inaccessible by other classes and files.

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```